# Use a variable inside a conversion function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is getting a list of dates. I need each value to be within a particular month. My Completed field is a DATETIME data type, so I am cutting the time portion off. My results image shows the output from the my query.

Am I able to replace the -1 in my StartOfMonth & EndOfMonth variables with my MonthsToGoBack variable so that I only have to change its value if I want a different month?

```
 = CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(m, @MonthsToGoBack, DATEADD(
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1kpu.png)

```
DECLARE 
    @MonthsToGoBack INT = -1,
    @StartOfMonth DATE = CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(m, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)), 101),   -- first day of the month
    @EndOfMonth DATE = CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()),0)), 101)       -- last day of the month
;
 
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CompletedDate, 101) AS CompletedDate 
FROM MyTable
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, CompletedDate) BETWEEN @StartOfMonth AND @EndOfMonth
```

I am currently seeing this error when I try it.

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 5
Must declare the scalar variable "@MonthsToGoBack".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 19
Must declare the scalar variable "@StartOfMonth".
```

Comment: What tool are you executing it in? Does it use semi colon as a batch delimiter?

Comment: I'm using SSMS. I don't need to use a semicolon.

Comment: Oh, I see I thought the error was coming from the `SELECT DISTINCT`. You just need to break the variable declarations up. To replace `-1` with `@MonthsToGoBack`.  You can't read from the variable in the same `DECLARE` statement as it is created in.

Comment: like so https://dbfiddle.uk/G3d8zGTL

Comment: @MartinSmith - I don't think the -1 in `DATEADD(d, -1, ...` should change. That was intended to always be -1 day.

Comment: Ah right - the gist of the fiddle was just to repro the error messages and show that they go away when splitting the declaration. I haven't really looked at what its doing. I imagine `EOMONTH` may well help. That is the only `-1` in that declaration and they said they were trying to replace in both

Comment: Side note: By using a conversion in `WHERE CONVERT(DATE, CompletedDate) BETWEEN ...`, you have reduced or eliminated the ability of SQL Server to use an index to filter on the  `CompletedDate` column. A better practice is to use an exclusive end date = 00:00:00 at the start of the next day (or month in your case) and then filter with `WHERE CompletedDate >= @StartOfFirstMonth AND CompletedDate < @StartOfMonthFollowingLast`. This nicely handles date/time ranges without truncation or imprecise "23:59:59.???" values. The query optimizer will thank you for it.

Comment: @MartinSmith - On a revisit, I realize I misinterpreted the code. I expect the OP wanted something like `@EndOfMonth = DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, -MonthsToGoBack+1, ... ))` or as you suggested `@EndOfMonth = EOMONTH(DATEADD(m, -MonthsToGoBack, ... ))` or even `@EndOfMonth = EOMONTH(@StartOfMonth)` in a separate statement. (This would of course be different if exclusive end date/time logic were used.)

Comment: @TN I will look into using the exclusive end date. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try and do all of the logic to set the variable's value in the declaration - you can DECLARE a variable first, and then SET its value in a subsequent statement.

```
DECLARE 
    @MonthsToGoBack INT = -1,
    @StartOfMonth DATE,
    @EndOfMonth DATE;

    SET @StartOfMonth = CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(m, @MonthsToGoBack, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)), 101);
```

Now the value of @StartOfMonth is set as you expect.  You can then use the same SET command to set the appropriate value of other variables, and then use them in later statements.